# Dynamically render list options

Tags: reactjs

Could someone show me what's wrong with the following code?
https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-feather-n7d70?file=/src/App.js

I have 2 lists (a, b,c ,d) and (e, b, f, g). I use @reach/listbox to display the list.

Expectation: When clicking on " Switch list" button, I would like to switch between those 2 lists

Reality: The reach Listbox shows empty

I would like to dynamically update the list options

Comment: I have seen that you have changed your code to using select, did that solve the problem ?

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem with Reach UI list boxes, if you try this with normal HTML select, it works.

https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-bird-uq3w2?file=/src/App.js